# Get infix algorithm from binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, avl-tree

[image]

Hi, I need to get four things from the binary tree

1. infix arithmetic expression GOT IT and tested:

> -4*(-5-2)/(-1*x-(-3))

2. Eval the expression with x = -1 GOT IT and tested:

> 7

3. infix arithmetic expression like if instead * is +

I tried to make this but all wrong:

```
-4+(-5-2)/(-1+x)-(-3)
-4+(-5-2)/((-1+x)-(-3))
-4+(-5-2)/(-1+x-(-3))
-4+(-5-2)/(-1+x)-(-3)
-4+(-5-2)/-1+x-(-3)
-4+(-5-2)/((-3)-(-1+x))
-4+(-5-2)/(-3)-(-1+x)

(-5-2)+(-4)/((-1+x)-(-3))
(-5-2)+(-4)/(-1+x-(-3))
(-5-2)+(-4)/(-1+x)-(-3)
(-5-2)+(-4)/-1+x-(-3)
(-5-2)+(-4)/((-3)-(-1+x))
(-5-2)+(-4)/(-3)-(-1+x)
```

4. Get the postfix arithmetic expression, I think should be this but no, is wrong too:

   45-2-*1x*-3--/-

   -4-52-*-1-3*/

I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not CS theory/homework

Comment: "I tried to make it but all wrong". What did you try to do exactly?

Comment: @kraskevich you see the long list after the `I tried to make this but all wrong` I made that, tried to replace the * with +, but not working, I don't know that i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is exactly not working? Did you tried to do it manually? Do you have an algorithm? If yes, you should probably post it.

Comment: @kraskevich but that is manually, I posted every conbination that I think is the answer.

Comment: @user3810795 How do you determine the correctness of the answer?

Comment: @kraskevich I put the answer into a system that validates if is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 3 is wrong on the first line (remember division and multiplication comes before addition and subtraction):

```
(-4 + (-5 - 2)) / ((-1 + x) - -3)
(-4 + -5 - 2) / (-1 + x - -3)
```

And Number 4 postfix notation (also known as reverse polish notation) you can get by depth first traversal, adding the parent node after both children were visited:

```
-4 -5 2 - * -1 x * -3 - /
```

Comment: Thanks @maraca, the 4 was correct, but the 3 not, but with your answer I got the correct one and is `(-4+(-5-2))/(-1+x-(-3))` Thank you very much !

Comment: Ah yes right, I made spaces to distinguish between unary and binary minus, but braces are probably better. Thanks for accepting.